# css background is not working when convert template into pdf using rendering plugin

Tags: css, grails, pdf-generation, rendering, gsp

I am using rendering plugin to generate pdf in grails.
I am using a background color which is prepared by css. code is here.

```
#container #content #mainContent .block .backgroundStyle {

    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 10%, #f49cd7 46%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(10%, #ffffff), color-stop(46%, #f49cd7), color-stop(100%, #ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 10%, #f49cd7 46%, #ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 10%, #f49cd7 46%, #ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 10%, #f49cd7 46%, #ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 10%, #f49cd7 46%, #ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

it is in style tag. its working fine when I see it at browser but when I am generating pdf color is not render. where am I wrong.

Comment: This [SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787221/grails-rendering-plugin-css-issue/15650855#15650855) should be helpful in your case.

Comment: thanks for reply. I am following same step as mentioned in  that link. Every thing is going fine but when I make an image using css then it does not show in pdf. while I am using @media print{ all css are here} but no effect.
one more Issue is coming ,I am using external font for my my pdf and  its also not not working for me.

Comment: Have a look at the docs for [Inline Image](http://gpc.github.io/grails-rendering/docs/manual/guide/7.%20Inline%20Images.html). Try to use `<rendering:inlineJpeg ...` or `<rendering:inlinePng .....>`. It works for me. For fonts, I am not sure whether you have to add that new font as a static resource.

Comment: for font I am using this syntax.

<style type="text/css">
  
    /* CSS Document */

@media print {



    font-face {
        font-family: 'binaryitc_ttlight';
        src: url('binaryitc.eot');
    }

    font-face {
        font-family: 'binaryitc_ttlight';
        url('binaryitc.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('binaryitc.svg#binaryitc_ttlight') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }
}
and add my font in page like this.
body {
        font-family: binaryitc_ttlight;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The rendering plugin uses itext 2.1.0 for creating the pdf. That is a very old version of itext (probably the last open source) and does not support CSS3 styles very well. Look at this other discussion [Compare these products for PDF generation with Java given requirements inside: iText, Apache PDFBox or FOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6625849/593644) for other available options.